# converting kph and heading to xyz velocity vector

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, vectors, spherical-coordinates

I am writing software (in C++) that is required to send out messages from our simulation system to another simulation system. Problem is we track the simulation object's current speed (kph) and heading (degrees) the other system needs a Velocity vector which is XYZ.

I have no idea how to do this. I unfortunately have a very weak trigonometry background and don't really understand vectors. I just need a formula to do the conversion. I could not find anything out there.
Please....

Comment: When you say "heading", that means to me a 2-dimensional coordinate system. Do you want a 3-dimensional system? If so, what exactly are the measurements that you track from the first system

Comment: Is your simulated object maneuvering around on a flat plane or on the surface of a sphere (e.g. the Earth)? Do you have any idea why there would be any non-zero z component in what you send to the other system? (If you know something about that, it could be a clue to what the conversion between the systems really is.)

Answer (score 1):

So what you're looking to do from a math perspective is go from spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates.

Basically your velocity vector in spherical coordinates includes three pieces of information: speed, horizontal heading, and vertical heading. You want your velocity vector in terms of X,Y, and Z. To do this, we use these equations:

$x=r \, \sin\theta \, \cos\phi$

$y=r \, \sin\theta \, \sin\phi$

$z=r \, \cos\theta$

Where $r$ is your speed, $\phi$ is your horizontal bearing, and $\theta$ is your vertical bearing.

Note: you didn't actually mention that you had a vertical bearing. I'm assuming you do since you asked for an X,Y,Z vector.

There's some more information on spherical coordinates [here on mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html).

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. So using my real example I am traveling 16.66 m/s going east. in our system due North is 0 degrees so that would be 90 degrees. We don't track any vertical angle but the receiving system does. So I need to send a Z value. Does my bearing need to be converted to radians? So   X = 16.66 * sin 0 * cos converted_to_radians(90).   Y = 16.66 * sin 0 * sin converted_to_radians(90).    Z = 16.66 * cos 0.   Is this right?  Again excuse my ignorance.  @rogerl

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate your vertical bearing theta if you also have your clime rate.

So for example if your clime rate is -20 ft/sec (aka descending) and your horizontal speed is 100 ft/sec.
Now in one sec you will have traveled 100 feet forward and 20 feet down

Then Tan(theta) =-20/100

```
theta = Atan2(-20/100)

This return value will be in radians

theta = -0.1973955 Rad

theta = -11.31 Deg
```

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)